# Tor not working?

Tags: internet, proxy, tor, websites

Our university provides us with internet but almost all websites are blocked. Not even general news reading websites. I tried to use tor but it is not even getting started.
All the proxy methods has also failed. Is there any other way to get access to all sites ?

Even sites which explain proxy steps are also blocked.. :'(

Comment: Are you using Tor itself, or the Tor Browser Bundle?

Comment: I am using tor only not the browser bundle...                

Aug 08 19:19:01.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server.
Aug 08 19:19:01.000 [notice] Heartbeat: Tor's uptime is 0:00 hours, with 1 circuits open. I've sent 0 kB and received 0 kB.          

It stops in this line forever....

Comment: Ah, I had a similar problem when I was back at Uni - but the browser bundle worked for me.. Give that a shot. I can't quite remember why the browser worked but not raw Tor..

Comment: Ok thanks.. I will try and return with the result :)

Comment: If the Tor site's blocked, here's a copy which shouldn't be blocked by your Uni (unless they dislike me!): http://elliotjreed.com/public/tor-browser-linux64-3.6.3_en-US.tar.xz and http://elliotjreed.com/public/tor-browser-linux32-3.6.3_en-US.tar.xz

Comment: I installed and tried to use tor and still i cant connect to the tor network :(Aug 08 23:46:49.565 [Notice] While fetching directory info, no running dirservers known. Will try again later. (purpose 6):::::I also used bridge addresses and still i can't connect...

Answer (score 0):

this is called system security and policy, be careful running third-party applications on university networks may result in you having your account suspended.  They will consider TOR third party in this case, especially as you are knowingly trying to circumvent security and policy.  It's not worth what your spending on your education, go to an internet cafe in town or buy a mobile-wifi dongle for your machine if you have one.